# Kivy: How to convert user input into int or float

Tags: python, kivy

When using `TextInput` in Kivy, everything that is entered is kept as a string, even when the input is restricted to characters that represent `float`s or `int`s using `input_filter`. How can `TextInput.text` be converted into an actual float or int type so that I can do calculations with it?

Comment: try casting to a float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `cast`

```
str_float = '123.456'
flt_val = float(str_float)
```

for `int`

```
int_val = int(str_int)
```

If the string is invalid integer, then it throws `ValueError` exception.
So,

```
try:
    int_val = int(str_int) # or flt_val = float(str_float)
except ValueError:
    # Handle exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you just grab the `TextInput.text` and convert it using `float` or `int`? ie `text = TextInput.text` for an int.. `conversion = int(text)`

Comment: int is going to fail on a float

Comment: Why I said for an `int` use the `int` cast, but you're right should have just used `float` cast as example to handle integers and floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In Kivy the TextInput defaults to unicode. So you will have to do lots of conversions.
Mostly back to floats and strings.

```
entry = float(entry)
entry = str(entry)
```